# AngularJS directive syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

and sorry for this noob question :)

With AngularJS, I want to display a progressbar using [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar).

The directive is working well if the value is hardcoded:

```
<progress percent="67"></progress>
```

But I've got an issue if I try with an object value in my template:

```
<progress percent="{{ myobject.progress }}"</progress>
```

Error message:

```
[Exception... "String contains an invalid character" code: "5" nsresult: "0x80530005 (InvalidCharacterError)" location: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js Line: 2"]
```

Could anyone give me the right syntax ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fiddler or plunkr please. Also you're missing a `>`

Comment: Thanks @Alan, for seeing this missing ">". Shame on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `progress` directive in Angular UI takes a reference to a scope value — the value isn't bound using double-curly braces.

So, you want your code to simply be:

```
<progress percent="myobject.progress"></progress>
```

You are seeing the error because Angular was trying to parse the parameter, and `{` and `}` are not valid inside an Angular expression.

You can see the correct use in the [Progress Bar documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar).  Notice there are no curly braces in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to set the isolate scope of your directive attributes so it will evaluate those correctly.  For example:

```
App.directive('progressbar', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            percent: '='  // this is the isolate scope you want to set appropriately.
        },
        ...
    };
});
```